# Check the value input between two column value.

Tags: mongodb

I have records which contain 3 columns 
`Title`
`MinValue`
`MaxValue`.

Now i am work on filter and wan to get the title of the my inputted value.

Records :

```
[
    {
        title : "1-10",
        minValue : 1, 
        maxValue : 10
    },
    {
        title : "11-20",
        minValue : 11, 
        maxValue : 20
    },
    {
        title : "21-30",
        minValue : 21, 
        maxValue : 30
    }
]
```

I need mondodb query which will return the record

> consider I input 5 then it will return first record

Answer (score 1):

You can use $gt and $lt parameters.

```
.find({ minValue : { $gt :  5}, maxValue : { $lt : 5 }})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
var target = 5;

db.foo.find({minValue: {"$lt":target}, maxValue: {"$gt":target}}, {_id:0,title:1});
```

The second arg to `find`is the projection.  It says do NOT show _id but do show title.